# Trouble using a UIButton to transition UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am a very inexperienced developer and have run into a problem that should be easy however after hours of reading over Apple's Developer guide and many different questions on this site I am still stumped.

All I am trying to do is transition from my root view controller to my next view controller via a UIButton.

Here is appdelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainViewController;

@interface MDAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

Important stuff from Appdelegate.m:

```
#import "MDAppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation MDAppDelegate


@synthesize window, navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

MainViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {

UIButton *cityButton;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *cityButton;

- (IBAction)chooseCityAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

And finally, MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "DailyDealViewController.h"


@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize cityButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }

return self;

}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [cityButton release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
    temporaryBarButtonItem.title = @"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
[temporaryBarButtonItem release];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setCityButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)chooseCityAction:(id)sender {

    DailyDealViewController *dailyDealViewController = [[DailyDealViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DailyDealViewController" bundle:nil];

    [dailyDealViewController release];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dailyDealViewController animated:YES];

}
@end
```

Here is the error:

```
2011-10-03 21:56:14.258 MD[4235:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x4b434c0>
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 
cityButton.'
```

I would love to know what I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have released `dailyDealViewController` before pushing it. Move the release statement to after the `pushViewController` statement.

Comment: Thanks Akshay, but I actually orginally had it like that and I was given the same error!

Comment: Well, it is CERTAIN that the release statement will be later. So, keep it that way. Have connected the button to the action in Interface builder?

Comment: Cool, I changed it back and it will leave it.

Comment: The button is connected to the Files Owner chooseCityAction as a Touch Up Inside. And I eventually need to hide it after it is pressed so I also connected under referencing outlet to File's Owner

Comment: Check your DailyDealViewController xib file. Ensure that the view controller is set to DailyDealViewController & not UIViewController. That should be the root cause.

Comment: :-/ Also good! I double checked but both view controllers are set to their respective names.

Comment: I am quite sure an incorrect name in the xib is the reason. Have you googled the error "this class is not key value coding-compliant"? It may help.

Comment: I have and I think tried everything that was said. Unless I am not understanding, when you say incorrect name in the xib you are reffering to the Identity Inspector, correct?

Comment: That is correct. In xcode 4, that would be in the Quick help section. Also, to be triple sure, right click on the xib name & select open as source code. Search for UIViewController & look for any invalid occurrences. Also, the problem seems to be in MainViewController's xib instead of DailyDealViewController, apologies for my previous comment.

Comment: thank you for the help, I am apologize for my lack of knowledge I opened up the source code and did not see anything obviously incorrect but I am not sure how to detect an invalid occurrence... where should I be looking?

Comment: You could try that by comparing the occurrences of UIViewController in MainViewController with those in DailyDealViewController? Are there any differences?

Comment: interesting enough i do not see UIViewController in any of them except "MainViewController"

Comment: <string>IBProxyObject</string>
   <string>IBUINavigationController</string>
   <string>IBUIViewController</string>
   <string>IBUICustomObject</string>
   <string>IBUIBarButtonItem</string>
   <string>IBUIWindow</string>
   <string>IBUIToolbar</string>
   <string>IBUINavigationBar</string>
   <string>IBUINavigationItem</string>

Comment: I apologize, that was from mainWindow... this is from MainViewController:

Comment: <string>IBProxyObject</string>
   <string>IBUIView</string>
   <string>IBUIButton</string>

Comment: That seems to be fine. I am running out of ideas, so you can perhaps try creating a new project from scratch. Maybe something got corrupt.

Comment: thank you for all your help. i started a new project today and it worked flawlessly! happy now but frustrated i could not find the root cause. thanks again.